# Getting last login time in Yii Framework

Tags: php, session, yii

I am a newbie to Yii framework. I had asked this question over Yii forum, but not got any good result, so I came here. Actually I want to show last logged in time when admin will login. It is available in Yii user module. So how to do that. Is it possible to get that time from user module to the index page.Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

[Update]

I followed [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/6/how-to-add-more-information-to-yii-app-user/) and I made Useridentity code like this as per instruction:

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;

    public function authenticate()
    {
        $user=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
        if($user===null)
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        else if($user->password!==md5($this->password))
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        else
        {
            $this->_id=$user->id;
            $this->setState('lastLoginTime', $user->lastLoginTime);
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

Now I have to call `id` and `lastlogin` in view file so that I can get the lastlogin time.So I have used this code in view file.

```
<?php echo Yii::app()->user->name;?>
<?php echo Yii::app()->user->lastLoginTime;?>
```

After all the changes I got the error like:

```
Property "CWebUser.lastLoginTime" is not defined.
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
Yii::app()->user->last_login =　$usermodel->last_login;
$usermodel->last_login = time();

echo "welcome back - your last login was at:".Yii::app()->user->last_login;
```

Comment: I made it in view file but it showed something error like this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE.

Answer (score 0):

you need just write that in your view when the user is logged

echo Yii::app()->user->lastLoginTime;

try it!

Answer (score 0):

You can not access to variables assigned via `setState()` directly

If you are using `setState()` you have to use `getState()` to get it:

**UserIdentity**

```
$this->setState('lastLoginTime', $user->lastLoginTime);
```

**view**

```
Yii::app()->user->getState('lastLoginTime');
```

or you can add one more private property like `$_id` and use it the same way. (i recommend it!)

Comment: This is nonsense. `CWebUser` is overwriting the `__set()` method in a way that session content is checked as well.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly and be all in the spirit of "have you tried turning it on and off again?", but as per [this comment](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/6/how-to-add-more-information-to-yii-app-user/#c2934), have you tried logging out and in again? I suspect the change hasn't affected your session yet which is why `CWebUser.lastLoginTime` cannot be accessed yet. See also the details of [CWebUser.__get()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser/#__get-detail).